# Angular : set reactive form with dynamic looping inputs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I've to set reactive form validation for a form where the inputs are made with data looping :

**my form builder would look like this :**

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'inputOne': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'inputOne': ['', [Validators.required]],
       ...
      'inputN': ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
```

**and my template would look like this :**

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
  <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;">
        <label for="lastName">{{item.name}}</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" [formControlName]="item.name">
      </div>
</form>
```

where items are loaded dynamically from my my backend

**How to populate controls dynamically in Angular reactive forms?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you want a form array here, not a group...

```
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    // build an empty form array
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.array([]); 
  }

  // call this whenever you need to add an item to your array
  private addItem(item) {
    // build your control with whatever validators / value
    const fc = this.formBuilder.control(i.lastName, [Validators.required]);
    this.userForm.push(fc); // push the control to the form
  }

  // call this function whenever you need to reset your array
  private resetFormArray(items) {
    this.userForm.clear(); // clear the array
    items.forEach(i => this.addItem(i)); // add the items
  }

<form [formGroup]="userForm">
  <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;">
    <label for="lastName">{{item.name}}</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" [formControlName]="i">
  </div>
</form>
```

notice you're using the index for the form control name here

Comment: Do you know how to refer to that kind of FC from this HTML template? Like lets say if `formControlName="{{ i }}"` how to tell if its value is `dirty` or something to show additional button?

Comment: nvm, I fond da wae - I'll leave this here for someone wondering about this, just like me:  
one can simply achieve this by calling `userForm.get([i])` and use it as a condition in ngIf for instance (`*ngIf="userForm.get([i]).value !== ''"`). Hope this helps someone